# unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall error on new operator

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have the following class and added the class's folder in my C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories

.h file

```
#include "PropertyCollectionPersistent.h"

namespace Pulsepay { namespace int_layers { namespace common
{
    using Pulsepay::server::common::CPropertyCollectionPersistent;
    using Pulsepay::server::common::CPropertySinkDefImpl;

    class CCommonSettings :
        public CPropertyCollectionPersistent,
        public CPropertySinkDefImpl
    {
    public:
        CCommonSettings(void);
        ~CCommonSettings(void);
    };
}}}
```

.cpp file

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Pulsepay_Int_Layers_Common_Settings.h"
#include "PropertyCollection.h"

using namespace Pulsepay;
using namespace Pulsepay::int_layers;
using namespace Pulsepay::int_layers::common;
using namespace Pulsepay::server;
using namespace Pulsepay::server::common;

namespace Pulsepay { namespace int_layers { namespace common { namespace details
{
    using Pulsepay::server::common::CProperty;

    static LPCTSTR  SettingAttribute__SettingStartUpSave     = _T("StartupSave");
    static LPCTSTR  SettingAttribute__DataProviderConnectStr = _T("DataProviderConnectStr");
    static LPCTSTR  SettingAttribute__LanguagePack_Key__Name = _T("LanguagePack__Key__Name");
    static LPCTSTR  SettingAttribute__LanguagePack_Key__Path = _T("LanguagePack__Key__Path");
    static LPCTSTR  SettingAttribute__DataProviderConnectDef = _T(".\\storage\\term2__local__main.mdb");
    static LPCTSTR  SettingAttribute__UseExternalDataSource  = _T("UseExternalDataSource");

    Pulsepay::server::common::Raw__PropertyItem  SettingAttribute__Enum[] = {
        {0xa1, SettingAttribute__SettingStartUpSave    , CProperty::EPT__Integer, _T("0") },
        {0xa2, SettingAttribute__LanguagePack_Key__Path, CProperty::EPT__Text   , _T(".\\PVSCLIENTAPP_USEGUIDE.LANG") },
        {0xa3, SettingAttribute__DataProviderConnectStr, CProperty::EPT__Text   , _T("") },
        {0xa4, _T("DataProviderDefaultURL")            , CProperty::EPT__Text   , SettingAttribute__DataProviderConnectDef},
        {0xa5, _T("NativeControlDataFile")             , CProperty::EPT__Text   , _T(".\\storage\\PVSUSERDATACTRL.TBL")},
        {0xa6, _T("NativeVeinImageDataFile")           , CProperty::EPT__Text   , _T(".\\storage\\PVSVEINDATA.DAT")},
        {0xa7, SettingAttribute__UseExternalDataSource , CProperty::EPT__Integer, _T("1")}
    };
}}}}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

CCommonSettings::CCommonSettings(void) : CPropertyCollectionPersistent(_T("CommonSettings"), *this)
{
    CPropertyCollectionPersistent::Create(details::SettingAttribute__Enum, _countof(details::SettingAttribute__Enum), false);
}

CCommonSettings::~CCommonSettings(void)
{
}
```

Now I whant to use above class from my project main function

When I don't use new operator I didn't get any errors

```
int_layers::common::CCommonSettings ccSetings();
```

Problem is appears when I use the new operator

```
int_layers::common::CCommonSettings *ccSetings;
ccSetings = new int_layers::common::CCommonSettings;
```

I get the following error

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Pulsepay::int_layers::common::CCommonSettings::CCommonSettings(void)" (??0CCommonSettings@common@int_layers@Pulsepay@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main

Please help!

Comment: When you don't use the new operator, all you are doing id declaring a function called ccSetings which returns int_layers::common::CCommonSettings.  You are not declaring a variable.  The link error is caused by the declaration of CCommonSettings being outside the namespace.

Comment: So what's the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but I want to be able to quote code properly:

```
namespace Pulsepay { namespace int_layers { namespace common { namespace details
{
using Pulsepay::server::common::CProperty;

static LPCTSTR  SettingAttribute__SettingStartUpSave     = _T("StartupSave");
// ...
}}}}    // All namespaces closed here.
```

So what's the namespace of the following definition:

```
CCommonSettings::CCommonSettings(void)
 : CPropertyCollectionPersistent(_T("CommonSettings"), *this)
{
   CPropertyCollectionPersistent::Create(details::SettingAttribute__Enum, 
   _countof(details::SettingAttribute__Enum), false);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean this problem releated with formatting ? I don't think so

Comment: No, I just want to point out that the namespace of the constructor definition doesn't appear to be the same as that of the class.

Comment: Wonder is that this class works with other porject